# Which content mode to use for scaling an image in an UIButton?

Tags: ios, xcode, image, uibutton, uistoryboard

I am developing a project for iOS, using storyboard for setting up the views.
If I have a `UIViewController` with some `UIButtons`, all of the same size.
Lets say 100 points width and 75 points height.

I have a variety of images, of all kinds of shapes, but all falling within this [100 width / 75 height] rectangle.
I want the images to keep their original size, shape & quality. So I guess I want to use center and/or aspect fit for content mode.
Is this the correct mode?
But aspect fit is especially needed, when an image is bigger then the `UIButton`, right?

What if the image is a fraction bigger then the [100 width / 75 height] rectangle, and I use aspect fit for content mode. This will 'scale down' the image to the size of the `UIButton`, right? Will the quality of the image decrease then? If yes, can this be a big decrease, or just marginal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I want the images to keep their original size, shape & quality. So I guess I want to use center and/or aspect fit for content mode. Is this the correct mode?**

*If you want button to change it's frame according to image then you should get `image.size` and update the frame of the button.*

**But aspect fit is especially needed, when an image is bigger then the UIButton, right?**

*Right!*

**What if the image is a fraction bigger then the [100 width / 75 height] rectangle, and I use aspect fit for content mode. This will 'scale down' the image to the size of the UIButton, right?**

*Right!*

**Will the quality of the image decrease then? If yes, can this be a big decrease, or just marginal?**

*Quality of image decrease when you scale up a Image. So Scaling down does;t make a big impact on image (if scaled in ratio).*

Comment: Ok makes sense, tx! I wanted to make sure I was on the right track, so this answer makes me more confident I am now

Comment: At the last question u mention: "(if scaled in ratio)". What do u mean here exactly? I am not yet 100% up to date on the subject

Comment: If you set content type to ScaleAspectFit then image is resized in aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

content mode `Aspect Fit` is always best choice while placing image anywhere in iOS